# Create an accumulator array from a function

Tags: plotting, functions, rounding

I am making some images for a project about the hough transform line detection, I am showing the slope-intercept form , the normal form and their accumulator arrays to show the peaks. I am kind of new to Mathematica.

```
Data = Table[{x, x + 1}, {x, -5, 5}];

Show[
 ListPlot[Data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 11}, Joined -> False]
 ]

pSIF[m_, x_, y_] := -x*m + y
pNF[t_, x_, y_] := x*Cos[t] + y*Sin[t]

Show[
 Plot[Apply[pSIF[m, #1, #2] &, Data, {1}], {m, -2.5, 2.5}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
 ]
Show[
 Plot[Apply[pNF[m, #1, #2] &, Data, {1}], {m, 0, Pi}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, Automatic}]
 ]
```

I have done the slope-intercept and normal form plots, but I don't know how to quantize the plot and make the accumulator array. I am trying to round it and move it to a table but without success.

```
Show[
 Plot[Round[Apply[pNF[m, #1, #2] &, Data, {1}]], {m, 0, Pi}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, Automatic}]
 ]
```

Comment: Greetings! Welcome to Mma.SE and **thanks for taking the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to first create these data points:

```
data2 = Flatten[
 Table[{m, #} & /@ Apply[pNF[m, #1, #2] &, Data, {1}], {m, 0, Pi, 0.1}], 1]
```

This gives you a list of points:

```
{ {0.,-5.}, {0., -4.}, ...., {3.1, -3.78}, {3.1, -4.74} }
```

Then you can use `BinCounts` to see how many of these point fit in a given bin (I am using bins of size 0.25x0.25 here:

```
 bc = BinCounts[data2, {Range[0, \[Pi], .25]}, {Range[-8, 8, .25]}]
 Grid[bc]
```

And then you can use `ArrayPlot` to visualize the bin counts (accumulator):

```
ArrayPlot[bc]
```

[image]

Let me know if I complete misunderstood your question?

---

Here is a slightly more complicated case, using more data points and two lines:

```
data = Join[
 Table[{x, -.45 x + 1}, {x, -5, 5, .1}], 
 Table[{x, 1.2 x - 1}, {x, -5, 5, .1}]
]
```

It looks like this:

```
Graphics[Point[data], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 5]
```

[image]

Again, compute `data2`:

```
data2 = Flatten[
 Table[{m, #} & /@ Apply[pNF[m, #1, #2] &, data, {1}], {m, 0, Pi, 0.1}], 1];
```

And get the bin counts `bc`:

```
bc = BinCounts[data2, {Range[0, \[Pi], .1]}, {Range[-5, 5, .1]}];
```

And make an array plot to visualize the bin counts:

```
ArrayPlot[bc]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, here is the result after some small changes, [images](http://imgur.com/a/xqwsA) , you have my thanks.

Comment: Good to hear my reply was useful. I know far too little in the area of hough and radon transforms, just enough to get myself into trouble. But these are powerful transforms and very useful in object reconstruction. There is also a built-in function `Radon` which does the radon transform.